# Why doesn't my 2nd PC connect to the internet wirelessly?

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp

I use the cable-provided router for wireless without difficulty on one computer (PC 1), but unable to connect with another computer (PC 2) simultaneously. I am unsure what step to take next to resolve the problem with PC 2.

- PC 1 uses DHCP for IP4 connections
- PC 1 pings opendns in 22ms average
- The router that BOTH computers use pings opendns in 13ms average.
- PC 2 DHCP populates the IP4 IP with 169.254.138.25.
- Changing PC 2 IP4 static connection of 192.168.0.99, mask 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.0.1 says the the the inet is secure and NOT connected.
- PC 2 DNSFLUSH completes successfully
- PC 2 uninstall and reinstall driver without difficulty
- Hosts file contains only the usual example lines preceded with number
- PC 2 wirelessly connects to a local hotspot on cell phone which is connected to the provider (sprint), speedtest.net is 23Mbps, ping 23ms.

PC 2 worked connected to the router 2 weeks ago. so I did a restore to a restore point 2 weeks old. No change in behavior.

I am stymied because:
PC 1 works fine wirelessly connected to the router
PC 2 works fine wirelessly connected to the the hotspot, but not the router.

Please suggest next steps.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you ever tried to connect pc 2 directly into the router using an Ethernet cable? If not, try it. If you have, what ip address did it give you? Also what Operating system are you using?

Comment: The IP range 169.254... indicates your PC is not talking to the router - ie your computer assigned it. Could the problem be related to the SSID/password the PC thinks the router uses being incorrect?